# Mootools stop form submit method

Tags: forms, mootools

I don't want to use an `<input type=submit />` button to submit a form and I am instead using an `<a>` element. This is due to styling requirements. So I have this code:

```
myButton.addEvent('click', function() {
    document.id('myForm').submit();
});
```

However, I have also written a class that improves and implements the `placeholder` attribute on `inputs` and `textareas`:

```
var FDPlaceholderText = new Class({
    Implements: Events,
    initialize: function() {

        var _self = this;
        var forms = document.getElements('form');        

        forms.each(function(form) { // All forms
            var performInit = false;
            var i = 0;
            var ph = [];
            form.getElements('input, textarea').each(function(el) { // Get form inputs and textareas
                if (el.getProperty('placeholder') != null) { // Check for placeholder attribute
                    performInit = true;
                    ph[i] = _self.initPlaceholder(el); // Assign the placeholder replacement to the elements
                } 
                i ++;
            });

            if (performInit) {
                _self.clearOnSubmit(form, ph);
            } 
        });

    },
    clearOnSubmit: function(form, ph) {
        form.addEvent('submit', function(e) {
            ph.each(function(el) {
                if (el.value == el.defaultValue) {
                    el.value = '';
                }
            });
        });
    },
    initPlaceholder: function(el) {

        el.defaultValue = el.getProperty('placeholder');
        el.value = el.getProperty('placeholder');

        el.addEvents({
            'focus': function() {
                if (el.value == el.defaultValue) el.value = '';          
            },
            'blur': function() {
                if(el.value.clean() == ''){ 
                    el.value = el.defaultValue;
                }
            }
        });

        return el;
    }
});

window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    new FDPlaceholderText();
});
```

The above class works great if a form is submitted using an actual `<input type=submit />` button: it listens for a submit and clears the inputs values if they are still the default ones therefore validating that they are essentially empty.

However, it seems that because I am submitting one of my forms by listening to a click event on an `<a>` tag the `form.addEvent('submit', function(e) {` isn't getting fired.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well you can change the click handler to fireEvent() instead of call the .submit() directly:

```
myButton.addEvent('click', function() {
    document.id('myForm').fireEvent('submit');
});
```

keep in mind a couple of things (or more).

1. placeholder values to elements that lack placeholder= attribute is pointless
2. if you detect placeholder support, do so once and not on every element, it won't change suddenly midway through the loop. you can go something like `var supportsPlaceholder = !!('placeholder' in document.createElement('input'));` - remember, there is no need to do anything if the browser supports it and currently, [near enough 60%](http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder) do.
3. you can otherwise do `!supportsPlaceholder && el.get('placeholder') && self.initPlaceholder(el);` - which avoids checking attributes when no need
4. when the form is being submitted you really need to clear placeholder= values in older browser or validation for 'required' etc will fail. if validation still fails, you have to reinstate the placeholder, so you need a more flexible event pattern
5. avoid using direct references to object properties like el.value - use the accessors like `el.get('value')` instead (for 1.12 it's getProperty)

for more complex examples of how to deal with this in mootools, see my repo here: https://github.com/DimitarChristoff/mooPlaceholder

Comment: Thanks for the tips. In regards to point 2 I found that if you enter blank spaces in browsers that do support placeholder the placeholder doesn't come back which is why I am overwriting the native support.

Comment: that's fine - your validation layer needs to be separate and in mootools, you can do `el.set('value', el.get('value').trim().stripScripts())` to normalise. trimmed empty strings will revert back to original placeholders - if you have any custom ones, make sure to also `.fireEvent('change')`

Comment: `fireEvent('submit')` won't submit the form, just run the listeners bound by MooTools, right?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `submit()` method is not from MooTools but a native one.

Maybe you can use a `<button type="submit">` for your styling requirements instead.